# use --trace for backtrace Error while compiling SCSS file

Tags: css, ruby, sass, scss-lint

I am trying to do

```
sass input src.scss test.css
```

or

```
sass input src.scss:test.css

Both results in error::
Errno::ENONET:No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - input
```

This is my first scss to css compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass a real created file:

```
# cd my_path_with_file
sass example.scss example.css
```

OR you can use absolute path to file:

```
# output file will be saved in current directory
sass my_path/example.scss example.css
```

Goodluck.